# Increase brightness of tiff file with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am working on a python script to get images from a microscope camera and then combine them to have an avi file.(15fps for 3sec).
I wrote a program but the final result is too dark.
I am looking for a solution to make it brighter.
When I add enhancer I get this error

```
ValueError: image has wrong mode
```

The camera gives 45 dat files .I converted them to tiff and then concatenated then to have an avi file.
The camera is  Andor Neo 5.5 sCMOS

Here is a part of my code:

```py
    with tifffile.TiffWriter('datfiles.tif', bigtiff=False) as tif:
        for datfile in datfiles:
            data = numpy.fromfile(
                datfile,
                count=width * height * 3 // 2,          # 12 bit packed
                offset=4,                               # 4 byte integer header
                dtype=numpy.uint8,
            ).astype(numpy.uint16)
            image = numpy.zeros(width * height, numpy.uint16)
            image[0::2] = (data[1::3] & 15) | (data[0::3] << 4)
            image[1::2] = (data[1::3] >> 4) | (data[2::3] << 4)
            image.shape = height, width
            #img = increase_brightness(image)
            tif.write(
                image, photometric='minisblack', compression=None, 
                                                                metadata=None)   
    

    img = Image.open('datfiles.tif')
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
    img=enhancer.enhance(4)

    
    for i in range(45):
        
        
        try:
            img.seek(i)
            img.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
        except EOFError:
            break
      
    os.remove("datfiles.tif")
    
    
    '''
    ------------------------------------------
    Concatenate the tif files ----> .avi of 3 sec
    '''
    image_folder =os.getcwd()                               #to be modified
    print(image_folder)                                     #testing
    video_name = "ConcatenatedVideo.avi"
    
    
    images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".tif")]
    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 15, (width,height))
    for image in images:
        video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

            
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()
    
    for f in os.listdir(image_folder):               #delete allthe tiff files
        if(f.endswith(".tif")):
            os.remove(os.path.join(image_folder, f))            
    print('finished')
    os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: As a *"quick fix"*, you could try shifting your image left 4 times before writing, i.e. `tif.write(image<<4, photometric=..., compression=...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now

Comment: error is a PIL error. check the involved image's mode.